# Cant access string.xml from headers.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, nullpointerexception

I have my headers.xml and im trying to move all texts to String.xml, and try to access from headers.xml

This is a fragment of header.xml

```
<header android:title="@string/str_Configuracion_general"/>
<header android:id="@+id/general_settings"
    android:title="General"
    android:fragment="com.thinkbig.interfaz.GeneralFragment"/>
<header android:id="@+id/paradas_settings"
    android:title="Paradas"
    android:fragment="com.thinkbig.interfaz.ParadasFragment"/>
```

Instead of using plain text in android:title="XXXXXXXXXX" I use strings.xml containing a string that have "XXXXXXXXXX" as value.

But i get the error listed below and dont know why, I already used this way before without any problem, but it doesnt work in this xml

```
/com.thinkbig.interfaz E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.thinkbig.interfaz, PID: 21669
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.thinkbig.interfaz/com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
at com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity.existeCabina2(MainActivity.java:1030)
at com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity.checkBornes(MainActivity.java:916)
at com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:2381)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5422) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here the strings.xml fragment:

```
<string name="str_Configuracion_general">Configuración general</string>
```

They're in different folders inside res, maybe i'm addressing wrong the @string/str_Configuracion_general

[Res folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgS9A.jpg)

Main Activity line 1026 and so on:

```
    public boolean existeCabina2(List<Header> target){
    boolean encontre = false;
    Iterator<Header> it = target.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext() && !encontre){
        if(it.next().title.toString().equals("Cabina 2")){  //line 1030 shown in error
            encontre = true;
        }
    }
    return encontre;
}
```

The code works perfectly if I use plain text, but if i change the plain text on headers.xml to get the string from strings.xml it throws the error.

Maybe its because "@string/str_Configuracion_general" is an int (reference) and then im trying to do a .toString() of it. 
How do I use the string of that reference? so then i can use it as a normal string.

Comment: What does the `*` do: `*"@string/str_Configuracion_general"*`?

Comment: I tried to use the italic font but didnt work make as it doesent exist

Comment: Yeah, those don't work in code blocks. You may want to *edit* your question.

Comment: <header android:title="@string/str_Configuracion_general"/> this is what i have on the xml originally i had ...title="Configuracion General"

Comment: Add, strings.xml also.

Comment: "at com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity.existeCabina2(MainActivity.java:1030)" What is line 1030 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: According to your Logcat the NPE, is in MainActivity. But as per your question, you want to access strings.xml in headers.xml.

Comment: Also chk at com.thinkbig.interfaz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:2381)
 What is at line 2381 of MainActivity.

Comment: `Iterator<Header> it = target.iterator();

if(it.next().title.toString().equals("Cabina 2")){....`

Comment: The program works perfectly if I write title="Configuración General" but not if i use "@string/str_Configuracion_general"

Comment: @SebastiánOtte: Please add the whole code. Cannot understand in comments.

Comment: @SebastiánOtte: If you are so sure then try to clean the code & rebuild the code. Then again try installing the apk.

Comment: 1. Please edit your question to include the code so that it is formatted well. 2. The code in your comment is most likely two lines of code. (If it isn't, it **should be**.) You need to tell us which of these lines is the one that causes the error. 3. You need to determine which part of the line causes the NPE. If it is the `if` statement, you should break it up into several lines because there are at least 4 possible places for the NPE.

Comment: 4. Use an enhanced for loop instead of a while loop: `for (Header header : target)`.

Comment: 5. How do you populate the `List` which is passed in as `target` to `existeCabina2()`?

Comment: List<Header> target = getHeaders(); that's the target that existeCabina2() received

Comment: The program works thats for sure, the thing is when i try to change the title from plain text to a reference from strings.xml maybe its some function that is used in the main program that doesnt accept the reference that i made, I dont know

Comment: I'm trying to do this so then all my texts will be in strings.xml, and then i can translate my app to different languages just editing a single file.